# python regex getting a multiple lines that begin and end with

Tags: python, regex

Hi I'm new to python and I need to extract data with a pattern

what my input is this

```
block_id: Fzu text: {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': 'start this is the line of
text i want to extract \n <www.test.nl|René Glaudemans> \n also
this end.', 'verbatim': False} type: section block_id: y0Z elements:
[{'type': 'button', 'action_id': 'yMLUy', 'text': {'type':
'plain_text', 'text': 'Bevestig', 'emoji': False}, 'style': 'primary',
'value': 'bevestigd'}] type: actions
```

The wanted output:

```
this is the line of text I want to extract \n <www.test.nl|René Glaudemans> \n also this.
```

Every time the wanted output starts and ends with the word "start" and ends with "end"

I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, it will work from first `start` to last `end`:

```
import re

regex = r"start\s(.+)\send"

strng = '''block_id: Fzu text: {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': 'start this is the line of
text i want to extract \n <www.test.nl|René Glaudemans> \n also
this end.', 'verbatim': False} type: section block_id: y0Z elements:
[{'type': 'button', 'action_id': 'yMLUy', 'text': {'type':
'plain_text', 'text': 'Bevestig', 'emoji': False}, 'style': 'primary',
'value': 'bevestigd'}] type: actions'''

s = re.search(regex, strng, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL).group(1)

print(s)

'this is the line of\ntext i want to extract \n <www.test.nl|René Glaudemans> \n also\nthis'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
pattern = "start(.*\n.*\n.*[\n].*).\',"
txt = """block_id: Fzu text: {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': 'start this is the line of text i want to extract \n <www.test.nl|René Glaudemans> \n also
this end.', 'verbatim': False} type: section block_id: y0Z elements:
[{'type': 'button', 'action_id': 'yMLUy', 'text': {'type':
'plain_text', 'text': 'Bevestig', 'emoji': False}, 'style': 'primary',
'value': 'bevestigd'}] type: actions"""

x = re.findall(pattern, txt)
x = repr(''.join(x))
x = ' '.join(x.rsplit('\\n', 1))
print(x)
```

output:

```
this is the line of text i want to extract \n <www.test.nl|René Glaudemans> \n also this end
```